# Progress Bar in C for an arbitrary long execution -- CONSOLE

Tags: c, progress

I have tried my best to search not only stackOverflow but other website as well but could not find something to match my needs. What I am requesting is to be able to display a progress bar (e.g. Progress: ####.........). I don't really care for the % at the moment.

Now lies the problem. I can not simply do a 0-100 for loop as the code I wish to have executed and tracked lies within a while loop that runs for an arbitrary time (problem size depends on input of user thus, is not constant).

I have thought of keeping track of the number of iterations within an int variable and try to do a modulo by 2, 50 or 100 but as I have said, the number of iterations depends on the users input and thus, only manageable under specific conditions. No other output but the progress bar is done so I do a simple printf('#'); inside the while loop and all the pretty stuff outside it.

This is also a personal preference but don't mind if not included, I would like the progress bar to be 50 characters long so 100% execution = 50 '#' characters accordingly.

Any help is kindly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So i wrapped the code from before nicelly and here is what i ended up with.

---

I used a little bit of `oop` concept and simulated the class of a `ProgressBar`. Here is how i designed the code for the `ProgressBar`:

```
struct tagProgressBarData
{
    unsigned long nMaxLen;
    unsigned long nCurLen;

    char FillChr;
    char EmptyChr;
    char LeftMargin;
    char RightMargin;
};
typedef struct tagProgressBarData PBD;

void InitProgressBar(PBD* p, unsigned long MaxLen, char Left, char Right, char Fill, char Empty);
void DrawProgressBar(PBD* p);
```

Before jumping to the definitions of `InitProgressBar()` and `DrawProgressBar()`, this is how you should use what i've made. Here is an example:

```
int main()
{
    PBD data;

    /** You can chose other characters and change the length too! */
    InitProgressBar(&data, 50, '[', ']', '#', '.');

    /** Now we do something which takes some time. */
    /** Let's just calculate some random cubes. */

    /** The N you talked about. */
    unsigned int N;
    printf("How many numbers to compute: ");
    scanf("%u", &N);

    printf("Calculating the cubes of the first %u numbers.\n", N);
    DrawProgressBar(&data);

    for(unsigned int i = 1; i <= N; i++)
    {
        unsigned int CubeResult = i*i*i;

        unsigned long nProgress = ( ((unsigned long long)i) * data.nMaxLen) / N;
        if (nProgress != data.nCurLen)
        {
            data.nCurLen = nProgress;
            DrawProgressBar(&data);
        }
    }


    return 0;
}
```

---

And now, the definition of the function that prints the progress bar:

```
void DrawProgressBar(PBD* p)
{
    /** Move to the beginning of the line. */
    printf("\r");

    /** Print the left margin char. */
    printf("%c", p->LeftMargin);

    /** Make sure that MaxLen >= CurLen */
    if (p->nMaxLen < p->nCurLen)
        p->nCurLen = p->nMaxLen;

    /** Print the progress with the Fill char. */
    for(unsigned long i = 0; i < p->nCurLen; i++)
        printf("%c", p->FillChr);

    /** Complete whats left with the Fill char. */
    for(unsigned long i = 0; i < p->nMaxLen - p->nCurLen; i++)
        printf("%c", p->EmptyChr);

    /** Print the right margin char. */
    printf("%c", p->RightMargin);
}
```

I have also used this function to make my code in main more compact:

```
void InitProgressBar(PBD* p, unsigned long MaxLen, char Left, char Right, char Fill, char Empty)
{
    p->nMaxLen = MaxLen;
    p->nCurLen = 0;

    p->LeftMargin = Left;
    p->RightMargin = Right;
    p->FillChr = Fill;
    p->EmptyChr = Empty;
}
```

---

If you want to have some text before the progress bar but on the same line (something like `Progress: [######.............]`) you have to replace the `printf("\r");` from the `DrawProgressBar()` with a `for` loop so you move back exactly the length of the progress bar.

Also, you need some variable (let's say `bDrawn`) which will tell you if the progress bar has been drawn at least once, so that the for loop will not move the cursor over the existing text at the left of the progress bar.

Comment: Hmmm, after setting some printf's inside your code, it would appear I get a floating point exception right before the for loop

    printf("How many numbers to compute: ");
    scanf("%u", &N);
    printf("Calculating the cubes of the first %u numbers.\n", N);
    for(unsigned int i = 1; i <= N; i++)

But I studied the code, this should be a good base for what I want and much more customizable.

Comment: @Mariosyian What do you mean by `floating point exception` ? There are no floats in my code. Also, i noted with a comment that having the progress bar length bigger than the input number `N` will crash because a `division by 0` will occur. The error is in the condition of the `for` that will check if there should be an update to the progress bar.

Comment: Yes, that is what I believe caused it. I am looking into that now. Will check as accepeted answer once I can see it fully working. The code is very good though! Thank you!

Comment: @Mariosyian Done! Found a new formula and placed it in `main`. Thats the best i could get without modifying the `ProgressBarData` and the functions that manipulate it.

Comment: Also note that i added a call to `DrawProgressBar` before the loop so that the progress bar is drawn with 0 progress.

Comment: @Mariosyian A reason why you unchecked my answer? What problems did you encounter with my code?

Comment: No trouble, it must have unchecked when I tried to post my new method as an answer. Sorry for that. I am new to stackOverflow post / answer system. I still consider yours a more appropriate answer.

Comment: @Mariosyian calm down :) i do not cry over rep, just asked if there was a problem

Answer (score 1):

I have also done this but seems to be very dependent on the number of items.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#include <time.h>

int MAX_PROGRESS = 100;
int BAR_LENGTH = 0;  // Length of Header
int num_items = 30;

void delay(int milliseconds) { 

  // Storing start time 
  clock_t start_time = clock(); 

  // looping till required time is not achieved 
  while (clock() < start_time + milliseconds); 
} 

void initialiseProgressBar(char left, char right, char fill) {

  printf("%c", left);
  for (int i = 0; i < BAR_LENGTH; i ++) {
    printf("%c", fill);
  }

  /** Print the right first (end of line) and then again the left (start of line)
   * as the \r will be placed over it and rewrite from there resulting in one
   * character less
   */
  printf("%c\r%c", right, left);
}

void drawProgressBar(char c) {

  // Print according to BAR_LENGTH
  for (int i = 0; i < 100; i ++) {
    double progress = (i / BAR_LENGTH) % (MAX_PROGRESS * BAR_LENGTH * num_items);
    if (progress == 0) {
      printf("%c", c);
      delay(25);
    }
    // Redraw the stdout stream to show progressing bar
    fflush(stdout);
  }
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {

  // Header
  char* header = "|<------------- Progress Bar ------------->|\n";
  printf("%s", header);
  BAR_LENGTH = strlen(header) - 3; // Account for newline and right character characters

  initialiseProgressBar('[', ']', '.');
  drawProgressBar('#');

  // Footer -- TODO Find better way to finish this without hard coding
  printf("] COMPLETED\n");
  return 0;
}
```

Assuming you know the number of items you are calculating against (e.g. sorting a list, calculating different things etc), this should come in handy :).

Answer (score 0):

After trial and error, I may have found a solution but would like to check against someone.

Assuming these variables (all of type int):

> num_iterations = 0, MAX_PROGRESS = 100, BAR_LENGTH = 50, num_items = N

I have printed a '#' character on:

```
if ((iteration / BAR_LENGTH) % (MAX_PROGRESS * BAR_LENGTH * num_items) == 0)
```

and get my desired result:

```
|<------------- Enumeration Complete ------------->|
|##################################################| COMPLETED
```

Though this gradually builds up, it is not of the form

```
|<------------- Enumeration Complete ------------->|
|##################################................|
```

Anything I can do with \r or \b?

Comment: Without using other function for printing, you can go back on the line of the console with the character with the asci code`8` (i do not know if it is called somehow or if has some \x code). An example: `printf("Hello, World! %c%c ", 8, 8);` will have no `!` at the end because it is overwritten by the space after the two characters.

Comment: Apparently the character with the code `8` is actually `\b`... so yes if you do not print a `\n` you can use the `\b` character to go back into the line and change the content displayed.

Comment: You should only post an answer when you have a complete answer to the question. If you have a new question, it's best to post a new question instead.